# Handling partial failures in case of Mono zip

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am building a reactive Java application in which I'm creating a zip of three different functions, say funA(), funB() and funC() in the following way

```
Mono<Type> combined = Mono.zip(funA(), funB(), funC())
                          .flatMap(...)
```

I want to achieve a behaviour in which I can control the response specifically on the basis of errors that may occur in A, B and C. For example: if A and B fail but C succeeds, then return successful with just C and so on, and return error only when all three of A, B and C fail. Is this possible to be achieved using project reactor?

Comment: Read the mono tag please.

Answer (score 2):

In case of error in any source `Mono.zip` will cause other sources to be cancelled and the return error signal. There is `Mono.zipDelayError` that will wait until all `Monos` have produced an item but if several Monos error, their exceptions are just combined.

We would need handling errors on every source using `.onErrorResume` and return non-error signal wrapping exception or result.

Here is some generic approach to wrap sources and handle results

```
Mono.zip(wrapError(funA()), wrapError(funB()), wrapError(funC()))
       .map(res -> {
            // handle res.getT1(), res.getT2() or res.getT3()
           
            // if (res.getT1().getError() != null) {
            //    ... use res.getT1().getResult()
            // }
        })
```

where

```
private <T> Mono<ResultWrapper<T>>  wrapError(Mono<T> momo) {
    return momo
            .map(res -> new ResultWrapper<T>(res))
            .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just(new ResultWrapper<T>(e)));
}

class ResultWrapper<T> {
    private T result;
    private Throwable error;

    public ResultWrapper(T result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public ResultWrapper(Throwable error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public T getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public Throwable getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```